# jquery scroll to bottom of modal window on click

Tags: jquery, scroll, bootstrap-modal

In a modal window, I have a div that is toggled open and closed. 
When opened, I need to have the modal window scrolled to the bottom. 
How can this be done? None of the 'usual' methods will scroll the modal window.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('.item-wrapper').hide();

    $(".item-toggler").click(function() {

        $(this).parent().find(".item-wrapper").toggle();

        // none of these scroll the modal window to the bottom 

        // $('#modal-body-content').animate({ scrollTop: 300 }, 500);

        // $("#modal-body-content").scrollTop(900);

        // $('html, body, .modal-body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: 500 }, 500, 'easeInOutExpo');

    });

});


<div class="modal-body" id="modal-body-content">

    <div class="item-wrapper"> a lot of content here </div>

    <div class="item-toggler">show the content and scroll to bottom of modal window</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Anshor tag to scroll to a define div, add this to your function :

```
window.location.href="#targetDiv";

e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

and in your html div :

```
action="#targetDiv"
```